# Imports with dependencies in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, pythonpath

I have a directory structure for my dags in airflow like so

```
dags/
    -dag1.py
    -libs/
        -depend1.py
        -depend2.py
```

in dag1.py, I import depend1.py from libs. However, depend1.py then imports depend2.py causing Airflow to throw a Broken Dag: No module named 'depend2.py'

I assume this is due to the PYTHONPATH starting from dags/ and the import in depend1.py imports depend2 rather than libs.depend2.

If I switch to using libs.depend2 it appears to work. My question is whether there is an alternative to manually altering each of these files to import from libs. as the dependencies have a large number of files that all have dependencies from each other as they are automatically generated classes for managing a custom XML schema.

Comment: pip install the dependencies to the virtual env that airflow will run them from?

Comment: @cmclel why you can't just make refactoring and remove recursive dependencies? looks like problem with your own code but not with `dags` or `airflow`.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar yeah this was a problem with the code I was using and I took the refactoring route. The problem was the classes I was importing were auto-generated for handling custom XML and there was a heap of dependencies that it did not set correctly.